# Select data based on string pattern

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation, filtering

I'm trying to select data from nested lists based on seconds.

This is my data:

```
data = {{"2020-08-16T13:00:22.5000000", 45.6332`, 
    0.75`}, {"2020-08-16T13:00:24.5000000", 45.6332`, 
    0.75`}, {"2020-08-16T13:00:26.5000000", 45.6332`, 
    0.75`}, {"2020-08-16T13:00:28.5000000", 45.6332`, 
    0.75`}, {"2020-08-16T13:00:30.5000000", 45.6332`, 0.75`}};
```

If i only wanted to select the list containing data from "2020-08-16T13:00:24*" for example, what is the best way of doing this?

I tried this but didnt work:

```
Select[data, First@Characters[First@#] == "2020-08-16T13:00:24*" &]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

```
Select[StringMatchQ["2020-08-16T13:00:24*"] @* First] @ data
```

> ```
> {{"2020-08-16T13:00:24.5000000", 45.6332`, 0.75`}}
> ```